# pull JSON data from a text file and put it in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, file

i have a text file named "vars.txt" that holds an array. How can i pull that information and put it in a javascript array? right now i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
  var testvar = <?php file_get_contents('vars.txt') ?>;
  alert ("success");
  alert (testvar);
};
</script>
```

and that is not working. is there a better way to pull this data into an array?

Comment: Right click -> view source... What you see is not valid javascript.

Comment: How is it now working? What is the error? What is actually happening?

Comment: if i try to call the function it says the function does not exist, but if i comment out the first line of the function it works fine

Comment: where exactly do you attempt to call it?

Comment: Is it possible you cannot use this function on local files for security reasons? Perhaps your host doesn't allow it. Or you use Windows? I think there is a documented bug on Windows related to this function, but I'm not sure it's relevant to your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
  var testvar = <?php echo file_get_contents('vars.txt') ?>;
  alert ("success");
  alert (testvar);
};
</script>
```

You forgot to `echo` the data, without this nothing will be rendered into the javascript function.

To debug situations like this, just view the source of the rendered webpage, and see what's actually printed.

Comment: i still get "test is not defined" when i attempt to call the function

Comment: In this case, your json file must be wrongly formatted. Have you viewed the source?

Comment: in php i'm using
file_put_contents('vars.txt', json_encode($varsphp));

to write json data to the file

Comment: my file itself looks like this    

[null,"offline.png","offline.png","offline.png","offline.png","offline.png","offline.png","Group A","Group B","Group C","Group D","Group E","Group F","","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","0"]

Comment: The file looks ok, but what is actually rendered into the page? You really need to view source.

Comment: In that case, PHP has not even processed your script, PHP or the web server is not installed and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` to decode the JSON data from `vars.txt`:

```
var testvar = <?php echo json_decode(file_get_contents('vars.txt')) ?>;
```

Comment: still saying function is not defined when i use this, if i comment it out the function works fine